# Building product family constraint in CPLEX

Tags: constraints, cplex

When I added constraints to make sure that the sum of flow of products in each products family must be equal to the flow of that product family from one stage to another stage, I am not sure whether it is right or not.

This is my code for that constraint. I denote that Q2 is the rate of flow of product i from warehouse m to distribution center k and Qf2 is the rate of flow of product family f from warehouse m to distribution center k. Family 1 includes products 1-6, 10. Family 2: 7-9, Family 3: 11-14.

```
 forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=6 || i==10) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==1)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=9 || i>=7) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==2)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i>=11) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==3)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
```

*r is the range of number of products that  Qf2 belongs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second constraint you wrote

```
sum(i in pr:i<=9 || i>=7)
```

You should write

```
sum(i in pr:i<=9 && i>=7)
```

which you can also write

```
sum(i in pr:7<=i<=9 )
```

instead

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your answer!